# Synergy connection time out (win 10 and Ubuntu)

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ethernet, synergy

I have a Windows 10 based pc and Ubuntu based laptop. My pc doesn't have a wireless network card so I'm connected to the internet through Ubuntu laptop. My pc is connected to the laptop with ethernet cable and laptop shares internet connection with my pc. When I open up synergy on my laptop it say that my ip addresses are: 10.42.0.1, 192.168.0.103. When I open up synergy on my pc it says that my ip addresses are: 10.42.0.82. I started the server on my pc but when I start the client on my linux laptop and try to connect to 10.42.0.82 connection always times out. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It was my dumb mistake. The server was on port 24800 and the client was on port 8081.